# How to have row without particular field as function param

Tags: purescript

What I want is following, I have a row type:

```hs
type FooBarBaz =
  ( foo :: Int
  , bar :: String
  , baz :: Boolean
  )
```

Then a need a function that takes this row type record but without "foo": and adds default "foo" field:

```hs
withoutFoo { bar: "bar", baz: true} -- > { foo: 1, bar: "bar", baz: true}
```

I tried to do something like this, but can not get it around:

```hs
withoutFoo :: ∀ r.
  Lacks "foo" r =>
  Cons "foo" Int r FooBarBaz =>
  { | r } -> { | FooBarBaz }
withoutFoo props = Record.union { foo: 1 } props
```

UPD:

managed to solve it with Union constraint:

```hs
withoutFoo :: ∀ r.
  Union r ( foo :: Int ) FooBarBaz =>
  { | r } -> { | FooBarBaz }
withoutFoo props =
  Record.merge props { foo: 1 }
```

Comment: Please don't tag your titles. Integrate them into your title question if appropriate.

Comment: What's the problem with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your function isn't actually generic. There is only one possible choice for `r`: it should always be `(bar :: String, baz :: Boolean)`

So just make that the type of your function:

```hs
withoutFoo :: { bar :: String, baz :: Boolean } -> { | FooBarBaz }
withoutFoo props = Record.union { foo: 1 } props
```

Comment: Thanks, though actually managed to solve it with Union constraint and Record.merge (updated OP).

Comment: That's a needless complication. In your solution, `r` is always `(bar :: String, baz :: Boolean)`

Comment: In the real use case I have quite a big row, that consists of many more than tree fields, and I resuse it in other places as well -)